# AngularJS: Still have 404 (Not Found) errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know the trick of using ng-src directive, but I still have 404 errors on img tag.

Here is the controller.

```
.controller('DetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$stateParams','Hairstyles',
    function($scope, $stateParams, Hairstyles) {
        Hairstyles.getDetails($stateParams.hairstyleId).then(function(data){
            $scope.hairstyle = data.hairstyle;
        });
    }])
```

Here is the service.

```
getDetails: function(postId) {
            return $http.get("http://example.com/hairstyle/api"+postId).then(function(result){
                return result.data;
            });
        }
```

Here is the view.

```
<img class="full-image" ng-src="http://example.com/files/large/{{hairstyle.photo}}">
```

I got the error like this in the Chrome's javascript console.

> GET http://example.com/files/large/ 404 (Not Found)

Note it's empty after the last slash(/). And don't worry about the data, it's correctly handled. The image is showing correctly after this error. However, I would just like to eliminate the error. It creates a lot of error logs on my server.

I believe this is simply because the synchronize problem of using http.get, can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe add `ng-if="hairstyle.photo"`

Comment: Move the base url into controller and do the concatenation there, in order to leave the ng-src to be empty before the data is ready.

Comment: What you get if yo do console.log($scope.hairstyle.photo) inside your controller?